# Gulp uglify and save license

Tags: gulp

I am trying to run Gulp and save license data like jQuery license info.

Gulp runs fine files are minimized but no license file:  This is what I have in my Gulp file.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
saveLicense = ('uglify-save-license'),
uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('default', function () {
gulp.src('scripts/*.js', {
    output: {
        comments: saveLicense
    }
}
).pipe(uglify()).pipe(gulp.dest('publish_folder/scripts'));
console.log('Task Completed');
});
```

I'm very new to Gulp.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The saveLicense object must be passed to the uglify plugin, not to gulp.src. Try this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    saveLicense = require('uglify-save-license'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    gulp.src('scripts/*.js')
        .pipe(uglify({
            output: {
                comments: saveLicense
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('publish_folder/scripts'));

    console.log('Task Completed');
});
```

PS: Also I think you make a typo, you forget to write require when loading *uglify-save-license* plugin.